# Is Win 10 (UWP) development like Win 8.1, WPF, or both?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I just upgraded to win 10, and I have a book for win 8.1 app development (which I have yet to start); I'm aware of a few perks to win 8.1 apps over WPF, and I'm wondering if the new WPF (if it is new beyond aesthetically) has these perks? Is there any reason to read this 8.1 book? Or are there large changes that I should just get a win 10 book?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 development is quite similar to Windows 8.1 development but the API surface area is larger in Windows 10, and when creating a Windows 10 app you should keep in mind multiple device families.

The key differences in Windows 10 are referencing device specific APIs requires an extension SDK, adaptive coding is introduced (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation), adaptive UI now utilizes window width and height (in effective pixels), and there is greater availability of some .NET APIs (as well as the .NET structure entirely).

To answer your "Is there any reason to read this 8.1 book?" question - if you are entirely unfamiliar with Windows development then yes, absolutely. It will help you get started with Windows 10 and it will probably be some time before comprehensive Windows 10 developer books get published. I would supplement it with some of the Universal Windows Platform blog posts/videos/etc...